# MS Word changing my fonts when pressing enter or commas

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am using Microsoft Word 2007 and I changed the style normal in order to use another font (`Droid Sans`), but when I press enter or insert sometime a comma, Word changes the font into Arial.

Yet in the Formatting option, I can see that it is my `normal style` which is selected

**How to prevent Word from changing it ?**

Comment: The font you're using might not have a character for `,` or Return, so Word is switching to one that does.

Comment: Do you think Droid Sans has got no comma?

Comment: Apparently not. Was just a guess.

Comment: With another font it would have been a good guess.

Comment: What happens if you select the transformed paragraph & press control-spacebar? Have you tried using Word's "reveal formatting" option?

Comment: Type a comma in Arial, highlight it, and change the font to Droid. This will at least tell you if the Droid font has a comma.

Comment: @Wutnaut it changed it succesfully

Comment: Something else is wrong with the font, then. I recommend typing the document in Arial and changing the font to Droid when you're done.